# Unable to preview report in SSDT - an attempt has been made to use a data extension "oracle" that is either not registered for this report server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a tricky issue , i want to build report from oracle database by SSRS
i'm installed oracle client , ODAC and ODP.NET .

but when i'm go to preview report this message is appeared.

**An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ORACLE' that is either not registered for this report serve or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services**

[Click to preview Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICWXa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is it oracle 11g?
You would probably need Oracle Client Components installed on your local machine (where you have SSRS installed) inorder to use the Connection Provider for an Oracle Database.

You might want to take a look at the link below: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

install according to your system configuration 32bit/64bit